# Reference Static member in Static Method In a Powershell Class

Tags: powershell, class, properties, static, powershell-5.0

Why does the direct access of a static fail, but the indirect works? Note that the file loaded is valid in both examples.

**Failure Using Direct To Static**

```
class OpPrj {

[string] $ProjectPath

static [string] $configFile = 'settings.json';

[OpPrj] static GetSettings(){
   return [OpPrj](Get-Content [OpPrj]::configFile | Out-String|ConvertFrom-Json);
}
```

**Works By Assigning to Local**

```
class OpPrj {

  [string] $ProjectPath

  static [string] $configFile = 'settings.json';

  [OpPrj] static GetSettings(){
      $file = [OpPrj]::configFile
      Write-Host $file  # outputs settings.json
      return [OpPrj](Get-Content $file | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json);
  }
```

Comment: Because your syntax is wrong: `(Get-Content ([OpPrj]::configFile) | ...`  This is the way you need to reference static properties for any type (or enum!) when dealing with parameter binding, that is, wrapped in parens.  I don't understand why the parser works that way here, but it does.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the `$this` automatic variable instead of `[OpPrj]::configFile` ?

Comment: @Theo `$this` doesn't exist for static members because they exist on the *type* not the *object*.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Ah, I didn't know that. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Put it as an answer, and I will mark it as such. thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your call to `Get-Content`:

```
Get-Content [OpPrj]::configFile
```

The PowerShell parser is unable to determine where this ends (I am uncertain of the reason), so you need to explicitly wrap it in parentheses (I also recommend being explicit about the parameter you're passing, especially in scripts, for readability):

```
Get-Content -Path ([OpPrj]::configFile)
```

You will need to follow this syntax for enums and static class members.

---

In all (your call to `Out-String` is unnecessary):

```
class OpPrj
{
    [string] $ProjectPath

    static [string] $ConfigFile = 'settings.json'

    static [OpPrj] GetSettings()
    {
        return [OpPrj](Get-Content -Path ([OpPrj]::ConfigFile) -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json)
    }
}
```

Comment: Mr. Ohio...thank you for the info on Out-String too. :-)